# How to dynamic change a class on EJS based on the URL

Tags: node.js, express, url, ejs

I'm learning EJS and I discover that I can do my sidebar in only one file and use it on my pages.

But now I don't know how to automatically change the "active" class on my anchors on the sidebar, there is a way to change it dynamically? My URL changes depending on the page i'm in, so I thought that I can change the class of my anchor based on that.

sidebar.ejs code:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <a href="/vendor" class="active">All Vendors</a>
    <a href="/expiring">Close to Expire</a>
</div>
```

I'm using EJS, NODE.JS and express...

Sorry for any English mistakes, it's not my mother language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this example,

```
#sidebar.js

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .active > a {
        color: red;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<script>

  var global_queryurl = window.location.href; 
  var url_pathfinder = new URL(global_queryurl);
  var global_queryurl_path = url_pathfinder.pathname; 
  var global_queryurl_spliter = global_queryurl_path.split('/');
  var global_pagename_val = global_queryurl_spliter[global_queryurl_spliter.length-1];

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".tab").removeClass("active");
      if(global_pagename_val == "vendor") {
        $("#1").addClass("active");   
      } else if(global_pagename_val == "expiring") {
        $("#2").addClass("active");   
      } else {
        $("#1").addClass("active");   
      }
  });
</script>

<!--sidebar-menu-->
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
  <li class="tab" id="1" ><a href="/vendor" >Vendor</a> </li>
  <li class="tab" id="2" ><a href="/expiring" >Expiring</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--sidebar-menu-->
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I did some adaptation, but you definitely helped me!